# Serilog Memory leak when logging large json

Tags: c#, .net, serilog, webapi

I have default logger configuration

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration();

Log.Logger = logger.CreateLogger();
```

When i send 30Mb json before hitting controller memory increase by 0.5GB

```
_logger.LogInformation($"Controller AddBatch {batch}");
```

This line cause increasing memory by 2GB. This memory is never disposed.

```
    [HttpPost(Name = "Test")]
    public string Test([FromBody] JObject batch)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Controller AddBatch {batch}");
        return "";
    }
```

Edited because i reproduced this on simple example

Comment: `_logger.LogInformation($"Controller AddBatchTimeLogs {batchTimeLogs}");` => Do not use string interpolation. It may not immediately _fix_ the whole problem, but surely it should improve the situation.

Comment: And also: do you _really_ need to log _the whole thing_? Sounds like overkill to me. And actually a vulnerability. A malicious client could just send a humongous json and blow you out of the water.

Comment: Duplicated to https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/1982 where there's some discussion.